# The question mark (?) in flex

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I cannot understand what the question means in a regular expression in flex. For example, in my notes it says:

> **[ a-z ]?**  corresponds to 0 or 1 repetition (used for optional parts).

and another example says:

> **-?[1-9][ 0-9 ]∗** corresponds to any nonzero integer.

I do not understand why these regular expressions correspond to their explanations. Can somebody explain these two?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what's left to explain? What don't you understand about "? corresponds to 0 or 1 repetition (used for optional parts)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` isn't specific to flex it is a part of most regular expression engines. It basically means that whatever comes before the `?` is *optional*, so it doesn't actually have to be there.

Specifically it means "Zero or one of the preceding element".

Examples:

```
Nov(ember)?              // matches November or Nov
Feb(ruary)? 23(rd)?      // matches Feb 23 or February 23 or February 23rd or Feb 23rd
colou?r                  // matches color or colour
```